# SAP/Open UI5 load object data from JSON

Tags: json, object, sapui5

I have a problem with Open UI5 / SAP. I have a JSON file 
and I am showing a list. If you click on the list item you get some information about the entry.

So my Code looks like this:

JSON:

```
[{
   "ID": 124, 
    "members" : [{
     "member1" : "Person1", "Name" : "Test"
      }]
}]
```

Controller:

```
...
_onRouteMatched : function (oEvent) {
            var oArgs, oView;
            oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
            oView = this.getView();

            oView.bindElement({
                path : "/Employees('" + oArgs.ID+ "')",
                events : {
                    change: this._onBindingChange.bind(this),
                    dataRequested: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(true);
                    },
                    dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                        oView.setBusy(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
...
```

View:

```
...
<f:content>
                            <Label text="{i18n>ID}" />
                            <Text text="{ID}" />    
                            <Label text="{i18n>members}" />
                            <Text text="{members}" />
...
```

My problem is that it shows under members: "[object Object]". I tried everything to access the object but I coulnd't.

Does anyone have an idea how to access e.g. the name of member1 ?

By the way: I don't know if members contains anything. Sometimes it has member1, sometimes member1 and member2 and sometimes no member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: My JSON model is wrong!

It has to look like this:

```
[{
   "ID": 124, 
    "members" : [{
           "FirstName" : "Test",
           "LastName" : "Max"
      }]
}]
```

How to Access it:

View

```
...
<f:content>
                            <Label text="{i18n>ID}" />
                            <Text text="{ID}" />    
                            <Label text="{i18n>members}" />
                            <Text text="{members/0/FirstName}" />
...
```